# Fire asp.net TextChangedEvent only when certain conditions have been met?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a TextChanged event wired on an asp.net textbox, it will fire everytime I add/remove a character.  Is it possible to only fire it if and only if the textbox meets certain conditions such as if the textbox has a non-empty string greater than 5 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this, if you're worried because of the postback cost, would be to have a javascript event handler for the onchange event.  In that javascript function you can quickly check to see if the length is greater than 5, and then do something to postback to the server (for example, the javascript function can click a hidden button that posts back, although there are other ways as well).

Example (uses jQuery):

First, the javascript:

```
    function checkTextBox() {
    var textBox = $('#<%=tbTest.ClientID %>');
    var hiddenButton = $('#<%=hdnButton.ClientID %>');
    if (textBox.val().length > 5)
        hiddenButton.click();
}
```

Then, these are the ASP.NET controls:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTest" 
 AutoPostBack="false" onchange="checkTextBox()" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hdnButton" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

This event will only fire after you click away from the textbox.  If you want to have it happen while they're typing, you can change it to another event like onkeyup.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but I am not sure how to do it. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why not check the contents of the TextBox within the event handler, and only proceed if it's greater than 5 characters in length?

Comment: I thought about this, but I was curious if it was possible to not have it fire at all, so not even go into the method.

Comment: @Xaisoft [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) that this event "Occurs when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server." I don't know of any way that you can suppress this event from being fired.

Comment: It's true this event will always fire when there's a postback, but if the textbox has AutoPostBack set to false, it won't postback as a result of the text changing.  It'll only fire the TextChanged event when something else causes a postback.